# Trouble parsing table with jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have been stuck on this for a few days now. I am attempting to create an app that is for the forum fightlockdown (its an MMA forum).

The area where I am running into trouble is on pages such as http://fightlockdown.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=1 where I would like to display each section in a table as a row but am having trouble grabbing only the sections i.e. UFC, The Ultimate Fighter, etc...

The closest I have been able to get is grabbing all of the anchor tags but there are obviously others on the page which could throw off my results if I don't remove them from the returned Elements correctly.

I have not been able to figure out how to get the table to narrow down my results since as far as I can tell doc.select("table.tborder") does not yield any results and neither does doc.select("td.alt1Active").

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very specific in what you are looking for, so I'll throw some code out there and see if it's what you are looking for.

On this page specifically, the divs you are trying to pull have one of two classes associated with them.  This code selects those divs and iterates over them and then prints out the anchor tags in the divs.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fightlockdown.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=1").get();
    for (Element div : doc.select("div.forumold_lock, div.old_lockwindowbg")) {
        System.out.println(div.select("a"));
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I think you may have inadvertently answered my question correctly. When i print the .text from  doc.select("div.forumold_lock, div.old_lockwindowbg") it prints exactly what i I was aiming for. Sorry I was not clearer with my question, I tried to be but that rarely goes as planned haha
Thanks a ton!

Comment: how did you determined the div classes? i have not been able to find them anywhere in the HTML nor have a couple of other people i asked about it.

i am trying to work on the next section (after clicking a link from this page) and ifi know how you determined these it would save me quite a bit of time plus hopefully teach me something about HTML/CSS

Comment: When I viewed the html source, the classes were in the divs.  Not sure why you cant see them.

Comment: are you using some html viewer? i was just viewing from my browser (Chrome) but also tried FireFox and IE

Comment: I was just doing System.out.println(doc); after the initial parse.

Comment: thats actually a really obvious idea i hadn't thought of, thanks yet again!